# Extract Euler rotation from matrix using Maya

Tags: python, maya, euler-angles, eulers-number

I am trying to extract the rotation of an object based on these values:

```
[ 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000,
0.33333334, -0.53828228, 0.00000000,
0.66666669, -1.07656455, 0.00000000,
1.00000000, -1.61484683, 0.00000000 ]
```

I am not quite sure how to do that properly.. I found a few solutions online but none worked for me since all values used on those examples were a bit different from the one above.
Does anyone know how to extract that using Python/OpenMaya?
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are those values? I _think_ quaternions would be complex numbers, so are these unpacked values including Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you have specified seem a little strange (and don't really have any context). Anyhow, within Maya, there are a few options for converting a matrix to Euler rotation angles.

1. Construct an `MTransformationMatrix` *(one of the Maya API classes)* and provide the matrix in question to the constructor. The `eulerRotation()` method will return the values *(although you may be limited to an XYZ rotation ordering?)*
2. Create a transform node. Specify the rotation-order you want to use by setting the rotation order flag on the node *(e.g. xyz, zyx, etc)*. Use cmds.xform to set the matrix for the transform. Now just use cods.getAttr to read the rotation angles.
3. Call: `MEulerRoation MEulerRoation::decompose(const MMatrix &matrix, RotationOrder ord)`, passing in the matrix, and the desired rotation order.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for you answer. I could confirm this morning that the numbers were totally wrong. Since I never didt that, I was assuming that it was correct.. but after getting some feedback and asking around, I could confirm that it was wrong. I am really I am sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for your help anyway.